# How to read different variables with one has a string with spaces from a file

Tags: c++

So I have a function which is supposed to read 6 variables in each line from a file, and then show them to console, the problem is the string RenterName if it includes a space, the code doesn't work properly. This is my code:
...

```
  void displayRentersInformations() {
int RenterID, Fine;
string RenterName, FlatNumber, Status;
ifstream in;
in.open("RentersInformation.txt");
if (!in) {
    cout << "There is no information to be shown! \n";
}
else {
    while (in >> RenterID >> RenterName >> FlatNumber >> Fine >> Status) {

        cout << RenterID << RenterName << FlatNumber << Fine << Status << endl;

    }
}
in.close();
}
```

this is an example of the text from the file:

223456000 Sami Ahmed A7 6000 Paid

so Sami Ahmed should be stored as string inside RenterName but the space between them is making the problem, I tried using getline but It didn't work or I just didn't use it the right way, how to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you know that none of the other fields contains a space?

Comment: `the code doesn't work properly` That's not true.

Comment: Do you have any control over the formatting of the input file?

Comment: @stark I have another function that controls the input of the other fields, my only problem is when the user enters his name and it includes a spcae, like Sami Ahmed, I need to know how to store it in 1 variable which is RenterName

Comment: You can put the first word in RenterID, the last 3 in Flat, Fine and Status, and everything in between in RenterName.  But that fails if any of the other fields could also contain spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the problem is the string RenterName if it includes a space, the code doesn't work properly.

No, the code still works the way it suppose to work. Consider 2 variables `a` and `b` and the following line in a file:

```
Hello from file
```

Now doing this:

```
in >> a >> b
```

will read "Hello" and "from" and NOT "Hello from" and "file" or "Hello" and "from file".

If you want a variable to contain whitespaces you need to change the file format. You could for example separate using a delimiter:

```
Hello, from file
```

and then use `std::getline()` to read the entire line an then split using the delimiter.